# Idempotent Kafka Producer writing to multi-partitioned topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Does an idempotent producer have to be transactional in order to ensure idempotency when publishing to a multi-partitioned topic? After reading Kafka documentation I am still unsure if it does or not.

My environment is Kafka 1.0 cluster and Kafka 1.1 client.

Answer (score 1):

Idempotent producer create an id which is send with the messages. With this id, the lead broker is able to say 'Oh, I already treated this message'.

[Idempotent producer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Idempotent+Producer) and [transactional messaging](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Transactional+Messaging+in+Kafka) are two different approaches of making a exactly-once messaging semantics.

So, no !

Comment: Is that definitely the case though because idempotency is required for a transactional producer, so they are not really different approaches to making exactly once messaging semantics.from my understanding.

Comment: My understanding is that a non-transactional idempotent producer just gives the ability to ensure that the same message is only written once to the cluster within a session whereas transactions in addition to idempotency allows you to have idempotency across producer sessions. Also it gives you the ability to ensure that all messages produced within a single transaction will either all be committed or nothing is. The transaction can also include the committing of the offset to the source topic so that you get an all or nothing within the transaction for both the consumption and producing side.

Comment: You're right. Idempotent producer doesn't implies transactional messaging , whereas transactional messaging implies idempotent producer, because it's an addition to the classic idempotent producer.